# Download file using axios and React

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I created a GET API that downloads a file when called. However, when I use axios to make the call, the file does not download. I found that axios is returning response:data blob format. How can I download the file?

API call using axios:

```
export const downloadFile = (fileId) => apiClient.get(`/download/${fileId}`)
```

React code:

```
function callDownloadFileApi(){
    downloadFile('f5aa890c-8085-4209-8c0c-ee8522d7fb8c')
    .then(response => console.log(response))
    .catch(error => console.log(error))
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

When you want to download something, it means that you want to get a file from the server and save it inside your local system (For example on your mobile phone), In this case calling an API to start downloading doesn't make sense.

You need to first get the file path from the server, and then download it with the help of the [react-native-fs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-fs) as @Fiston Emmanuel said.